# Full year calendar display in Ionic 4 App

Tags: calendar, ionic4

I am trying to implement a full year calendar view on a page in Ionic 4 App. But unable to find a suitable npm-package/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this library [ionic calendar](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar) ? The version  0.5.x is working on ionic 4. Moreover, you can see an example in this [link](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-calendar-app)

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! But this library is not for year wise calendar display. I can see this is for month, week and day basis calendar display.